# What SQL Query to Get employeeId that hadn't Got Message?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a program that sends WhatsApp messages to many people in my office. One day, I sent a message but somehow my laptop's screen got off and my program stopped sending the message.

The program uses such employeeId in main_employee table then send message to their phone number. After that, a messageId is generated with one to many relationship. I identify that in messageId 1471 had sent to 427 of 830 employees.

main_employee table

```
+------------+
| employeeId |
+------------+
| 1          |
+------------+
| 2          |
+------------+
| 3          |
+------------+
| etc        |
+------------+
| 830        |
+------------+
```

messageReceiver table

```
+-----------+------------+
| messageId | employeeId |
+-----------+------------+
| 1471      | 1          |
+-----------+------------+
| 1471      | 2          |
+-----------+------------+
| 1471      | 3          |
+-----------+------------+
| 1471      | 4          |
+-----------+------------+
| 1471      | 5          |
+-----------+------------+
|           |            |
+-----------+------------+
| 1471      | 427        |
+-----------+------------+
```

My question is by using SQL query, how can I get employeeId that hadn't got messages?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all empployee that didn't get a specific message.

Add a messeageId = 2 reduces the resultset to specific messages

But it isn't that fast, and need some indexes

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE tABLE main_employee (employeeId int);
INSERT INTO main_employee VALUES(1),(2),(3);
CREATE TABLE messageReceiver (messageId int, employeeId int);
INSERT INTO messageReceiver values (1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT messageId, employeeId
FROM 
(SELECT distinct i.messageId, e.employeeId 
 FROM main_employee e cross join messageReceiver i
union all
SELECT messageId, employeeId
FROM messageReceiver) u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM messageReceiver mr 
                  WHERE  mr.messageId = u.messageId AND mr.employeeId = u.employeeId)
                  AND messageId = 2
group by messageId, employeeId 
order by messageId, employeeId;
```

| messageId | employeeId |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7To9yjc4W3w6t7EMj2izui/5)

Comment: what is 'SELECT 1' (line 8) query mean?

Comment: mysql and mariadb ignore all select columns in an EXISTS query so it doesn't reqally matter what you write the if it finds a match it ignores the row because of the not EXISTS

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot @nbk